# PRG multiple images upload => have a problem fixing images missing from temp folder

Tags: php

Code below works fine without PRG, BUT i want PRG because i really hate refresh-repost. Though, i did not foresee that problem: i assume that if i dont upload my images immediately with post, get wont find any files to move from temp folder to server folder (they are deleted immediately after post i guess?).

Now, since images should be uploaded before filtered anyway (using server sided languages), i had an idea of uploading without using PRG, and then using a session state like a temp file that will include all the submit info in order just to destroy it and get refresh-repost free... well, its not working. I know it uploads only the correct files, BUT i cant get any $vars out of it, resulting in being unable to show my $error variables / warnings for users.

So... how do i get two birds with one shot php gurus?

---

trying to figure out if 'fake' sessions can work:

```
<?php

session_start();

include_once('../includes/connection.php');

if (isset($_SESSION['logged_in'])) {

    if (isset($_POST['submit_pic'])) {

        $countfiles = count($_FILES['image']['name']);
        $target_dir = "../images/";
        $error_array = array();
        $upload_array = array();
        $eupload_array = array();

        for($i=0;$i<$countfiles;$i++)   {

            $filename = $_FILES['image']['name'][$i];
            $target_file = $target_dir.$filename;
            $uploadOk = 1;
            $imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
            $check = getimagesize($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"][$i]);

            if($check !== false) {
                $uploadOk = 1;
                if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
                && $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
                    array_unshift($error_array, "Image $filename is not JPG, JPEG, PNG or GIF.");
                    $uploadOk = 0;
                }
            } else {
                array_unshift($error_array, "File $filename is not an image.");
                $uploadOk = 0;
            }
            if (file_exists($target_file)) {
                array_unshift($error_array, "Image $filename already exists.");
                $uploadOk = 0;
            }
            if ($_FILES["image"]["size"][$i] > 500000) {
                $u = 1;
                array_unshift($error_array, "Image $filename is too large.");
                $uploadOk = 0;
            }
            if ($uploadOk == 0) {
                array_unshift($eupload_array, "Sorry, image $filename was not uploaded.");
            } else {
                if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'][$i], $target_file)) {
                    array_unshift($upload_array, "Image $filename has been uploaded.");
                } else {
                    array_unshift($eupload_array, "Sorry, $filename there was an error uploading your file.");
                }
            }

        } 

    }

    if(strcasecmp($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'],"POST") === 0) {

        $_SESSION['postdata'] = $_FILES;
        header("Location: ".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?".$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
        exit;
    }
    if( isset($_SESSION['postdata'])) {

        $_FILES = $_SESSION['postdata'];
        unset($_SESSION['postdata']);

    }

?>

    <!DOCTYPE html>

    <html lang="en">

        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
            <link rel='stylesheet' href='../assets/style.css'/>
            <title>CMS TEST</title>
        </head>

        <body>

            <div class='container'>

                <a href='add_picture.php' id='logo'><h2>Add Picture</h2></a>

                <br/>

                <small class='test_warning' style='color:#B83333'>
                    &#10102; Images should be JPG, JPEG, PNG or GIF format extentions. <br/>
                    &#10103; Images should not be above 500KB size.<br/>
                    &#10104; Please try to rename images before uploading for easier use.
                </small> <br/><br/>

                <form action='add_picture.php' method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <input type="file" name="image[]" id="image" class="custom-file-input" multiple required/><br/><br/><br/>
                    <input type="submit" value="Upload" name="submit_pic"/>
                </form>

                <?php if (!empty($upload_array)) { ?>
                    <small style='color:#00FF00'>
                    <?php echo '<br/><br/>', implode("<br/>",$upload_array), '<br/>'; ?>
                    </small>
                <?php }?>
                <?php if (!empty($eupload_array)) { ?>
                    <small style='color:#aa0000'>
                    <?php echo '<br/><br/>', implode("<br/>",$eupload_array), '<br/>'; ?>
                    </small>
                <?php }?>
                <?php if (!empty($error_array)) { ?>
                    <small style='color:#aa0000'>
                    <?php echo implode("<br/>",$error_array), '<br/>'; ?>
                    </small>
                <?php }?>

                <br/><br/>
                <a href='index.php'>&larr; Back</a>
                <br/>

            </div>

            <a class='logout' href='logout.php'>Logout</a>

        </body>

    </html>

<?php

} else {
    header('Location:index.php');
}

?>
```

'proper one':

```
<?php

session_start();

include_once('../includes/connection.php');

if (isset($_SESSION['logged_in'])) {

    if( strcasecmp($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'],"POST") === 0) {
        $_SESSION['postdata'] = $_FILES;
        header("Location: ".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?".$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
        exit;
    }
    if( isset($_SESSION['postdata'])) {

        $_FILES = $_SESSION['postdata'];

        $countfiles = count($_FILES['image']['name']);
        $target_dir = "../images/";
        $error_array = array();
        $upload_array = array();
        $eupload_array = array();

        for($i=0;$i<$countfiles;$i++)   {

            $filename = $_FILES['image']['name'][$i];
            $target_file = $target_dir.$filename;
            $uploadOk = 1;
            $imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
            $check = getimagesize($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"][$i]);

            if($check !== false) {
                $uploadOk = 1;
                if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
                && $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
                    array_unshift($error_array, "Image $filename is not JPG, JPEG, PNG or GIF.");
                    $uploadOk = 0;
                }
            } else {
                array_unshift($error_array, "File $filename is not an image.");
                $uploadOk = 0;
            }
            if (file_exists($target_file)) {
                array_unshift($error_array, "Image $filename already exists.");
                $uploadOk = 0;
            }
            if ($_FILES["image"]["size"][$i] > 500000) {
                $u = 1;
                array_unshift($error_array, "Image $filename is too large.");
                $uploadOk = 0;
            }
            if ($uploadOk == 0) {
                array_unshift($eupload_array, "Sorry, image $filename was not uploaded.");
            } else {
                if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'][$i], $target_file)) {
                    array_unshift($upload_array, "Image $filename has been uploaded.");
                } else {
                    array_unshift($eupload_array, "Sorry, $filename there was an error uploading your file.");
                }
            }

        } 

        unset($_SESSION['postdata']);

    }

?>

    <!DOCTYPE html>

    <html lang="en">

        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
            <link rel='stylesheet' href='../assets/style.css'/>
            <title>CMS TEST</title>
        </head>

        <body>

            <div class='container'>

                <a href='add_picture.php' id='logo'><h2>Add Picture</h2></a>

                <br/>

                <small class='test_warning' style='color:#B83333'>
                    &#10102; Images should be JPG, JPEG, PNG or GIF format extentions. <br/>
                    &#10103; Images should not be above 500KB size.<br/>
                    &#10104; Please try to rename images before uploading for easier use.
                </small> <br/><br/>

                <form action='add_picture.php' method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <input type="file" name="image[]" id="image" class="custom-file-input" multiple required/><br/><br/><br/>
                    <input type="submit" value="Upload" name="submit_pic"/>
                </form>

                <?php if (!empty($upload_array)) { ?>
                    <small style='color:#00FF00'>
                    <?php echo '<br/><br/>', implode("<br/>",$upload_array), '<br/>'; ?>
                    </small>
                <?php }?>
                <?php if (!empty($eupload_array)) { ?>
                    <small style='color:#aa0000'>
                    <?php echo '<br/><br/>', implode("<br/>",$eupload_array), '<br/>'; ?>
                    </small>
                <?php }?>
                <?php if (!empty($error_array)) { ?>
                    <small style='color:#aa0000'>
                    <?php echo implode("<br/>",$error_array), '<br/>'; ?>
                    </small>
                <?php }?>

                <br/><br/>
                <a href='index.php'>&larr; Back</a>
                <br/>

            </div>

            <a class='logout' href='logout.php'>Logout</a>

        </body>

    </html>

<?php

} else {
    header('Location:index.php');
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Besides temp pictures not existing between post get requests, also the variables are deleted from refreshing and i could not use them inside my html to show errors.

So i tried to play around with sessions even more, i moved the pic upload code to post, created some sessions to store my error arrays, and then at get i recreated my error arrays from the sessions i created for them.

Problem solved, pics are filtered, errors displaying, PRG is working.

Gosh... i just started with php there are soooo many things i dont understand D:

```
<?php

session_start();

include_once('../includes/connection.php');

if (isset($_SESSION['logged_in'])) {


    if( strcasecmp($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'],"POST") === 0) {

        $_SESSION['postdata'] = $_FILES;

        $error_array = array();
        $upload_array = array();
        $eupload_array = array();

        $countfiles = count($_FILES['image']['name']);
        $target_dir = "../images/";


        for($i=0;$i<$countfiles;$i++)   {

            $filename = $_FILES['image']['name'][$i];
            $target_file = $target_dir.$filename;
            $uploadOk = 1;
            $imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
            $check = getimagesize($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"][$i]);

            echo $_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"][$i];

            if($check !== false) {
                $uploadOk = 1;
                if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
                && $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
                    array_unshift($error_array, "Image $filename is not JPG, JPEG, PNG or GIF.");
                    $uploadOk = 0;
                }
            } else {
                array_unshift($error_array, "File $filename is not an image.");
                $uploadOk = 0;
            }
            if (file_exists($target_file)) {
                array_unshift($error_array, "Image $filename already exists.");
                $uploadOk = 0;
            }
            if ($_FILES["image"]["size"][$i] > 500000) {
                $u = 1;
                array_unshift($error_array, "Image $filename is too large.");
                $uploadOk = 0;
            }
            if ($uploadOk == 0) {
                array_unshift($eupload_array, "Sorry, image $filename was not uploaded.");
            } else {
                if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'][$i], $target_file)) {
                    array_unshift($upload_array, "Image $filename has been uploaded.");
                } else {
                    array_unshift($eupload_array, "Sorry, $filename there was an error uploading your file.");

                }
            }

        } 

        $_SESSION['error_array'] = $error_array;
        $_SESSION['upload_array'] = $upload_array;
        $_SESSION['eupload_array'] = $eupload_array;


        header("Location:add_picture.php");
        exit;
    }
    if( isset($_SESSION['postdata'])) {

        $error_array = $_SESSION['error_array'];
        $upload_array = $_SESSION['upload_array'];
        $eupload_array = $_SESSION['eupload_array'];

        unset($_SESSION['postdata']);
        unset($_SESSION['error_array']);
        unset($_SESSION['upload_array']);
        unset($_SESSION['eupload_array']);

    }

?>

    <!DOCTYPE html>

    <html lang="en">

        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
            <link rel='stylesheet' href='../assets/style.css'/>
            <title>CMS TEST</title>
        </head>

        <body>

            <div class='container'>

                <a href='add_picture.php' id='logo'><h2>Add Picture</h2></a>

                <br/>

                <small class='test_warning' style='color:#B83333'>
                    &#10102; Images should be JPG, JPEG, PNG or GIF format extentions. <br/>
                    &#10103; Images should not be above 500KB size.<br/>
                    &#10104; Please try to rename images before uploading for easier use.
                </small> <br/><br/>

                <form action='add_picture.php' method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <input type="file" name="image[]" id="image" class="custom-file-input" multiple required/><br/><br/>
                    <input type="submit" value="Upload" name="submit_pic"/>
                </form>

                <?php if (!empty($upload_array)) { ?>
                    <small style='color:#00FF00'>
                    <?php echo '<br/><br/>', implode("<br/>",$upload_array), '<br/>'; ?>
                    </small>
                <?php }?>
                <?php if (!empty($eupload_array)) { ?>
                    <small style='color:#aa0000'>
                    <?php echo '<br/><br/>', implode("<br/>",$eupload_array), '<br/>'; ?>
                    </small>
                <?php }?>
                <?php if (!empty($error_array)) { ?>
                    <small style='color:#aa0000'>
                    <?php echo implode("<br/>",$error_array), '<br/>'; ?>
                    </small>
                <?php }?>

                <br/><br/>
                <a href='index.php'>&larr; Back</a>
                <br/>

            </div>

            <a class='logout' href='logout.php'>Logout</a>

        </body>

    </html>

<?php

} else {
    header('Location:index.php');
}

?>
```